# MediaRecorder is not supported in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

`[Log] Webcam permission error`

`Error: MediaRecorder is not supported`

I am trying to record audio. Audio recording is working fine in Chrome Browser. But throwing an error in Safari.

`global.audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });`

`global.audioChunks = [];`

`const canRecord = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs=vp8');`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

MediaRecorder API is supported in Safari from version 14.1 (Released 2021-04-26).

There are 2 ways how to handle this issue:

- Inform user that Safari update is required for this functionality (easy, but not so delicate and not acceptable if old Safari support is required);
- Implement a server-side recording - send media stream via WebRTC to any media server (Janus, MediaSoup; GStreamer can be also used) and record it at server side - much more complicated, but 100% working with older Safari versions (starting from Safari 11). You'll need a media server installed and any kind of load balancing for high load, but it's the only one way how to implement it in browsers without MediaRecording API support.

Comment: I am using Safari web browser 16.4. not working.

Comment: Try to run this fiddle in your Safari:
https://jsfiddle.net/2mqb63of/3/

If MediaRecorder API is enabled, it should alert the Inactive state.

Comment: Safari does not support the same format for recording as Chrome, see https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/